# rails3 new_relic prevents production console from loading with undefined method `episodes_enabled?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, console

in Gemfile:
group(:production) do
  gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 3.0.0'
end

Irritatingly tries and fails to load in console.  Any tips?

```
  # RAILS_ENV=production rails c
/u/apps/new/releases/2011/vendor/plugins/rpm/lib/new_relic/control/frameworks/rails.rb:33:in `install_episodes': undefined method `episodes_enabled?' for #<NewRelic::Control::Frameworks::Rails3:0xa16d3e8> (NoMethodError)
  from /u/apps/new/releases/2011/vendor/plugins/rpm/lib/new_relic/control/frameworks/rails.rb:28:in `init_config'
  from /u/apps/new/releases/2011/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.0.0/lib/new_relic/control/instance_methods.rb:60:in `init_plugin'
  from /u/apps/new/releases/2011/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.0.0/lib/newrelic_rpm.rb:36
  from /u/apps/new/releases/2011/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
  from /u/apps/new/releases/2011/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
  from /u/apps/new/releases/2011/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
  from /u/apps/new/releases/2011/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
  from /u/apps/new/releases/2011/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
  from /u/apps/new/releases/2011/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
  from /u/apps/new/releases/2011/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
  from /u/apps/new/releases/2011/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
  from /u/apps/new/releases/2011/config/environment.rb:5
```

Comment: Just a comment, you don't need to pass in RAILS_ENV to console. You can just do "rails c production".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have both new_relic gem and new_relic plugin installed in vendor/plugins.

We use new_relic, but only the gem (not the plugin).  I would check why you have both plugin and the gem installed.  It's possible plugin is old.

K

Comment: Argh, stupid git for not removing deleted files with deployment.  Thanks!